# How to show pdf file coming from cloud server

Tags: php, html

I have pdf link file coming from cloud server and i put it into iframe to show it but when i open the page, it direct to download this pdf file and didn't show the file itself, also i used embed and object and it doesn't appear anything.

```
<iframe src='{$finalurl}' width='1000' height='1000' align='center'></iframe>
```

Comment: depends on the MIME type sent by the server, and also whether your browser has a PDF viewer (native or plugin) built in. Not all do. And it won't get triggered anyway unless the MIME type is mapped to it in your browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you required to use an i-frame?

And do you just want to show it, or download it to your 'own' server and show it? That's a big difference.

If you just want to show it (and keep it where it is):

```
<embed src="http://cloudservice/yourpdf.pdf" width="1000" height="1000" type='application/pdf'>
```

Good luck